# Remove datatable row if any column value is empty c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq, datatable

I need to remove the row from datatable even if any column in the datatable has empty values.

For Example :

My datatable has two columns

```
 Value     Input
  Dep     Phase 1
  Sec     
  Div     Phase 2
```

Result

```
 Value     Input
  Dep     Phase 1
  Div     Phase 2
```

I want to remove the second row as Input column has empty values. I'm stuck with the below code.

```
dtTable = dtTable.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
          .Where(row => !row.ItemArray.All(field => field is DBNull || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(field as string))).
          .CopyToDataTable();
```

Can anyone suggest me how this can be achieved ?

Comment: what is the issue you facing ?

Comment: you need `Any` not `All`

Comment: @RahulAgarwal - I'm not able to delete a row even if any of its column has empty values.

Answer (score 1):

According to the requirements you are mentioning you would need to use `Any` which will check that if at least column has `null` value or empty string it would filter out that row. So, do like:

```
row => !row.ItemArray.Any(field => field is DBNull || 
                                string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(field as string))
```

### EDIT:

If your all columns are of type `string` then the above code would work fine, otherwise you will need to convert it to string explicitly by calling `ToString()`:

```
row => !row.ItemArray.Any(field => field is DBNull || 
                                string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(field.ToString()))
```

This will now only return those rows for which every column has value in it.

Comment: what if column is not a string?

Comment: then we would need to do some work to check for exact type or we can convert it to string via `.ToString()`

Comment: @Alexey, null should be converted to empty string and then after trim() function check length of that string either zero or not?

Answer (score 1):

If for loop can be used. We can check each row and column for nulls

```
    for (int i = dt.Rows.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {

      if (dt.Rows[i]["col1"] == DBNull.Value || dt.Rows[i]["col2"] == DBNull.Value)
      {
           dt.Rows[i].Delete();
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for (int i = dt.Rows.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
    if (dt.Rows[i]["Column2"].ToString() == "")
        {
            dt.Rows[i].Delete();
            dt.AcceptChanges();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Code-only answers are not particularly helpful. Please add some descriptions of how this code solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
 for (int i = dt.Rows.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                {
                    if (dt.Rows[i][1] == DBNull.Value)
                    {
                        dt.Rows[i].Delete();
                    }
                }
                dt.AcceptChanges();
```

it remove empty rows in th data table